# Привязка команды к нажатию клавиши в TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть текстовое поле и кнопочка рядом. Кнопочке назначена команда. В качестве параметра передается текст текстового поля. Вопрос, а как ту же самую команду использовать для текстового поля по нажатии клавиши Enter, например?

Comment: Привязать команду к инвенту - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897775/wpf-binding-ui-events-to-commands-in-viewmodel

Comment: Привязать хоткей к команде - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10209609/3768545

Comment: @Monk, ага, то же самое нашел. Но решение с интерактивом мне не понравилось, поэтому в итоге я пришел к InputBindings )

Comment: @Monk, исправьте пожалуйста заголовок вопроса. Не знаю, как грамотно написать суть вопроса в одном предложении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="Ссылка на команду" CommandParameter="{Binding Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Точно так же можно привязываться к действиям мыши через `MouseBinding`.

Comment: `InputBinding` выглядит хорошо, да